# Divided column by 10^n

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I would like to create new column in my transformation

[image]

From JSON I receive let's say two colums (instrument, price) but the price is in integer value (for example: 1.24124 -> 124124). From the table input I get instrument and decimal places, so I would like to create column that take price (from Json input) and divide it by 10^(decimal) (from Table input). I do not know how to do it.

Comment: You want to make a simple division by 10 (I.E.: 255/10 = 25.50) ? If that is it you need to use the calculator, or even the Formula Step. One quick note though, make sure both numbers are in Meta Value Number (Use a Select Values step for that.)

Comment: No, I would like to devide the number by 10^n depends on the instrument that is in the column instrument.